# warning: `auto-ref` (bin "auto-ref") generated 1 warning

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I get this warnig from the rust compiler, when running the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let test = 3;
    let bar = Bar(test);
    (&bar).foo();
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Bar(i32);

impl Bar {

    fn foo(self) -> () {

        println!("{:?}", self);
    }

}
```

I wanted to try out the auto-ref rule on `fn method_name(self)`.

I run cargo 1.61 on termux.

Can anyone explain to me what the actual warning is or how I can get it to be displayed?

EDIT:
Here's the termux console output

```bash
~/auto-ref/src $ cargo run
warning: Hard linking files in the incremental compilation cache failed. Copying files instead. Consider moving the cache directory to a file system which supports hard linking in session dir `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/auto-ref/target/debug/incremental/auto_ref-2c1jpkoha1tv/s-gbbxgywkr4-kv6r95-working`

warning: `auto-ref` (bin "auto-ref") generated 1 warning
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.11s
     Running `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/auto-ref/target/debug/auto-ref`                            Bar(3)
~/auto-ref/src $
```

Comment: [The playground doesn't display any warning](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=807b0aad9242cdbecda52825addbb799).

Comment: How are you calling Cargo? And what exactly was the output from that call? Is it possible that you were calling Clippy (`cargo clippy`)?

Comment: I edited the question to include the console output. Cargo clippy displays the same warning.

Comment: Ah damn, I think I might have gotten confused because of the warning text. It's probably about the linking warning.

Comment: Also I think I tried the feature in the wrong way. I should have a method that takes &self and pass it a Bar directly.

Comment: This looks to be a warning triggered by the filesystem on which you execute cargo, and has nothing to do with the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understand now. What I thought was a warning was just the warnings summary. I got confused because I tried to test a rule that says that a &self method argument can automatically be referenced when using it on type self. The warning mentions auto-ref -- hence my confusion
-- but I think is actually about the linking warning.

What I tried was the following;

use the aut ref rule such that you do

```rust
bar.foo()
```

instead of

```rust
(&bar).foo()
```

.
Also the example code doesn't even do this. Here would be the correct example.

```rust
fn main() {
    let test = 3;
    let bar = Bar(test);
    bar.foo();
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Bar(i32);

impl Bar {

    fn foo(&self) -> () {

        println!("{:?}", self);
    }

}
```